# Creating new file in the same folder as the working file before creating new file?

Tags: geany

I'm working in the file *foo.py*, and press Ctrl+N to create a new file, then using Ctrl+S to save the new file, and Geany require selecting a folder to save the new file. How to tell Geany automatically choose the folder of the working file before creating new file (i.e folder contains file *foo.py*) to save the new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the treebrowser plugin and it's function "New file". Support inside Save-as-dialog would be a feature request on [github](https://github.com/geany/geany).

Answer (score 0):

Here without plugins and mouse I use the VTE (embeded terminal) to create file  easily :

- hit `<f4>` to get focus on the VTE
- type `geany newfile.ext` or `geany path/to/newfile.ext`
- hit `<f2>` to go back to editor, you are now in the n`newfile.ext` tab
- edit `newfile.ext`
- hit `<ctrl+s>` to save file at the previous given name & path

Easy & fast !